# Making my whole <div> clickable

Tags: php, html, css

I want to make the whole "topic" div clickable. You can see the code down below. I tried using `<a href="##"> </a>`before the first div but it will only make the picture clickable and not the whole div.

```
<?php
   $toppic = $app->get_topics();
   foreach($toppic as $topic){
    echo '<div id="topic">';
    echo '<div id="topicimg">';
      if(file_exists('assets/images/profielfotos/'.$topic['klant_id'])) { 
   echo '<img class="img-circle" src="/assets/images/profielfotos/'.$topic['klant_id'].'/'.$topic['foto'].'" />';
      } else {
         echo '<i class="fa fa-fw fa-user img-circle"></i>';
      }
      echo '</div><div id="topictekst">';
      echo '<b><a href="https://####/reactie"> '.$topic['topicnaam'].'</b></a>'; 
      echo '<a> - ' . $topic['voornaam'] . " " . $topic['achternaam'] . '</a>' ;
      echo '<a style="float:right; margin-top:15px;"> reacties</a> <span style="float:right; color:grey; margin-top:15px"class="fa fa-comment"></span>';
      echo '<hr><a><span class="badge bg-red">' . $board['topic'] . '</span></a>';
      echo '</div></div>';
     }
  ?>
```

[How it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hvPG.png)

**This works!**

now the only problem is that because I cant nest the `a` tag I am not abble to display the `reacties` on the right because it was styled with a `float: right`.

```
<?php
       $toppic = $app->get_topics();
       foreach($toppic as $topic){
        echo '<a href="https://####/reactie"><div id="topic">';
        echo '<div id="topicimg">';
          if(file_exists('assets/images/profielfotos/'.$topic['klant_id'])) { 
       echo '<img class="img-circle" src="/assets/images/profielfotos/'.$topic['klant_id'].'/'.$topic['foto'].'" />';
          } else {
             echo '<i class="fa fa-fw fa-user img-circle"></i>';
          }
          echo '</div><div id="topictekst">';
          echo '<b> '.$topic['topicnaam'].'</b>'; 
          echo ' - ' . $topic['voornaam'] . " " . $topic['achternaam'] ;
          echo ' reacties <span style="float:right; color:grey; margin-top:15px"class="fa fa-comment"></span>';
          echo '<hr><span class="badge bg-red">' . $board['topic'] . '</span>';
          echo '</div></div></a>';
         }
      ?>
```

Comment: The PHP is irrelevant here. Post the rendered HTML and CSS.

Comment: You have links inside the div. What happens if that gets clicked on? You aren't allow to nest links.

Comment: @Quentin I deleted the other `<a href>`when I added the other one

Comment: @j08691 I added it to the question

Comment: You can nest links inside a clickable div all you want. Bots will still navigate to the links, because they will not render the js click events on the div. But what you have is quite the mash.

Comment: You close the `</b>` tag incorrectly - inside the `<a>` element instead of outside. You can wrap the whole div with a single `<a>` element and not add inner `a` tags

Comment: Oh, and you're outputting multiple elements with the same ID - Don't do it, use classes instead

Comment: @AlonEitan Look at my question again

Comment: The `This doesnt work!` part obviously doesn't work because you didn't read all the comments about what to fix.

Comment: which one didnt I fix? @IncredibleHat

Comment: Look at the logic. You ***cannot nest*** `a` tags ***into each other***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because you have nested `a` element, which is invalid HTML - This is how to do it:

```
<?php
    $toppic = $app->get_topics();
    foreach($toppic as $topic){
        echo '<a href="https://####/reactie"><div class="topic">';
        echo '<div class="topicimg">';
        if(file_exists('assets/images/profielfotos/'.$topic['klant_id'])) { 
           echo '<img class="img-circle" src="/assets/images/profielfotos/'.$topic['klant_id'].'/'.$topic['foto'].'" />';
        } else {
            echo '<i class="fa fa-fw fa-user img-circle"></i>';
        }
        echo '</div><div class="topictekst">';
        echo '<b> '.$topic['topicnaam'].'</b>'; 
        echo '<span> - ' . $topic['voornaam'] . " " . $topic['achternaam'] . '</span>' ;
       echo '<span style="float:right; margin-top:15px;"> reacties</span> <span style="float:right; color:grey; margin-top:15px"class="fa fa-comment"></span>';
       echo '<hr><span class="badge bg-red">' . $board['topic'] . '</span>';
       echo '</div></div></a>';
    }
?>
```

Note that I replaced the `id` attributes with `class` because you can't have multiple elements with the same ID, so in your css/JS selector you need to address those as `.topic { <style> }` instead of `#topic { <style> }` (Same goes for `.topicimg`)

edit - If you want to show the *"reacties"* before the icon you can change this line:

```
echo '<span style="float:right; margin-top:15px;"> reacties</span> <span style="float:right; color:grey; margin-top:15px"class="fa fa-comment"></span>';
```

With

```
echo '<span style="float:right; margin-top:15px;"> reacties <span style="color:grey;" class="fa fa-comment"></span></span>';
```

By removing `float:right;` from the inner comment icon span and wrapping both the text and the icon in a single `span` that is floating to the right

Comment: Thx this helped a lot! Stil a little question: Is it possible to show the `reacties`before the icon? because it now float right like it suppose to do but the text `reacties` is after the icon and I want it to be in front of it

Comment: Well the problem now is that the icon is not on the right but on the left next to the text :#, maybe I need to add a `<p>` or something?

Comment: Thanks a lot mate! <3 , If you are also good with sql you might take a look at my other question if you want :3. And I tried making the color of the text black but it didnt work it tried using text-decoration:none and color:black but that didnt do it for me

Comment: Atleast some help with the last question might help, with making it black

Comment: Try changing `echo '<a href="https://####/reactie"><div class="topic">';` to `echo '<a href="https://####/reactie" style="text-decoration:none;color:black;"><div class="topic">';`

Answer (score 2):

Try to embrace your div in the a tag.

Examples are:

```
<a href="www.google.com">

     <div></div>
</a>
```

In the above example, you should be able to click anywhere on your div and you should land on google's page.

Well in HTML5 it is allowed to have a block content like div to be placed inside an anchor tag. This depends on the HTML version your a using because it will not work in HTML 4.

Comment: Look at my question again please, this code doesn't do it!

Comment: @IncredibleHat well if you look at my question as you can see it didnt work in my case?

Comment: @Canyouhelme We cannot help you out with php, because php itself is translated into html code. It would be helpful to look at the generated html using Chrome`s developer tool

Comment: I give up. But this answer doesn't deserve a downvote.

Comment: @IncredibleHat I found the problem your answer did it

Comment: If you look at the question i voted as the right anwer i got a qeustion if you know how to change it that it wont be blue but just black. I tried `text-decoration:none` and `color:black` but that didnt do it for me